# How to make a POST API call to a webservice in angular 7?

Tags: angular, rest

I need to send data to a text mining web service to extract metadata from it. I came up with the following code after following documentation but am getting an error for var in the first line.

I have tried replacing var data with data:string to declare the variable but it didn't work.

```
var data = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" *XML Data*";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
});

xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:40002/");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cookie", "JSESSIONID=1gsl3g26oa2l71jmauv312tub9");
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/xml");

xhr.send(data);
```

The error message is

> "Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was
>   expected."

Comment: Angular HTTP Client can be helpful to you https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using Angular 2+ version. Below are the steps

```
//import the HttpClient
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

//initialize the same in the constructor
constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

//Use the HttpClient instance http to post the call

var fd = new FormData();
   let username = environment.username;
   let password = environment.password;
   let authToken = btoa(username + ":" + password);

   const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.emc.documentum+json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + authToken,
      })
    };

    fd.append('data', JSON.stringify(docObj));
    this.http.post(URL, fd, httpOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its recommended to use angular HTTPClient from Angular 2.0 . And its best to keep service api separate from angular components so they can be reused. Write a service as below

Write a service using angular HTTPClient myservice.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http'; //HttpClient is an improved replacement for Http. They expect to deprecate Http in Angular 5 and remove it in a later version.
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment'

let httpOptions: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpOptions = httpOptions.append('Accept', 'text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*');
httpOptions = httpOptions.append('Content-type', 'application/text/octet-stream');
httpOptions = httpOptions.append('Authorization', 'my-auth-token');
httpOptions = httpOptions.append('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, must-revalidate');
//other headers as per your requirement

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DemoGetService {

  statusurl = '/getStatus'; // provide full url of server id thats what you prefer or specify the server url in environment.ts file
  statusparamsurl = '/getStatusWithParams';
  serverdataurl = '/getDataFromServer';

  http: HttpClient;

constructor(http: HttpClient) {
     this.http = http;
}
/** GET data from the server */
getServerStatus() {
  return this.http.get(environment.endpointbaseurl + this.statusurl, { headers: httpOptions , responseType: 'text'})
  // return this.http.get(this.statusurl, { headers: httpOptions , responseType: 'text'}) // if you declared statusurl with fullpath
}
getServerStatusWithParameters(param1, param2) {
  return this.http.get(environment.endpointbaseurl + this.statusparamsurl, { headers: httpOptions, params: { param1: param1, param2: param2 }, responseType: 'text' }) 
}

getServerData(param1,param2): Observable<MyDataObservable[]> { 
    return this.http.get<MyDataObservable[]>(environment.endpointbaseurl + this.serverdataurl, { params: { param1: param1, param2: param2 } }) 
    }
}
```

and in your angular component, invoke the service call as below

```
ngOnInit(){
this.MakeServerCall
}
MakeServerCall()
{
    this.Getp4000Service.getBlockConverterParameters()
    .subscribe(response => { 
        // parse response from server
     },
         function(error) { console.log("Error happended" + error.error.text); });
  }
```

A POST service can be done very similarly

```
sendData( parameters) : Observable<MyDataType> {
      return this.http.post<MyDataType>(environment.endpointbaseurl + this.serverurl, parameters, httpOptions)
}
```

Where you have observables you need to specify the structure of them